# Gradle not signing for nexus repo

Tags: java, maven, gradle, nexus

I'm having an issue signing my artifacts to publish to Sonatype Nexus Repo:

[image]

Below is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'signing'
    id "com.palantir.git-version" version "0.12.3"
    id "io.github.gradle-nexus.publish-plugin" version "1.0.0"
}
Properties properties = new Properties()
def propertiesFile = project.rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (propertiesFile.exists()) {
    properties.load(propertiesFile.newDataInputStream())
}


group 'com.github.ekimeel'
version gitVersion()
ext.isReleaseVersion = !version.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")
sourceCompatibility = 1.8


task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar, javadocJar
}

signing {
    sign publishing.publications
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            def releaseRepo = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
            def snapshotRepo = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
            url = isReleaseVersion ? releaseRepo : snapshotRepo
            credentials {
                username = properties.get("ossrh.username") ?: System.getenv("OSSRH_USERNAME")
                password = properties.get("ossrh.password") ?: System.getenv("OSSRH_PASSWORD")
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) { publication ->
            from components.java

            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact javadocJar

            pom {
                groupId = 'my-group-id'
                name = 'my-proj-name'
                description = 'my-desc'
                url = 'my-url'
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id = 'my-id'
                        name = 'my-name'
                        email = 'my-email'
                    }
                }
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name = 'The Apache License, Version 2.0'
                        url = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection = 'my-scm-conn'
                    developerConnection = 'my-dev-conn'
                    url = 'my-url'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The signing is failing because plugin id `signing` - expects you to put signing **keyId**, **password** and **secretKeyRingFile location** in your project's gradle.properties. Its mentioned [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html#sec:signatory_credentials)

For reference, it says your gradle.properties should have

```
signing.keyId=24875D73
signing.password=secret
signing.secretKeyRingFile=/Users/me/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

Will update once I figure out how to pass those values from local.properties but that seems to be the issue you are facing.

---

This is all assuming that you have signing keys available in your system. *If not, first complete GPG (or cygwin for windows) setup and generate yourself a keyId and password for the project.*